# Select de todas as empresas que possuem catálogos

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Estou com um problema em um `select` em duas tabelas que estão retornando o valor duas vezes.
Tenho a tabela **empresas** e tabela **catalogos** que são ligadas por **empresa.id** e **catalogos.id_empresa**. Quando faço um `select` que tem dois ou mais catálogos de uma mesma empresa, aparece a empresa mais de uma vez.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_empresa` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_catalogos` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tbl_empresa_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tbl_empresa_id` (`tbl_empresa_id`)
)
```

Eu preciso selecionar todas as empresas que possuem catálogos.
Como faço isso? Como seria a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar as **empresas** que possuem **catálogo** você precisa fazer um `join` com catálogos, mas como você não precisa exibir todos os **catálogos**, somente as **empresas**, você tem duas alternativas: selecionar somente as empresas com `distinct` ou selecionar somente empresas usando um `group by` nela.

Com `distinct`:

```
select distinct e.* from tbl_empresa e 
join tbl_catalogos c on (e.id = c.tbl_empresa_id);
```

Com `group by`:

```
select e.* from tbl_empresa e 
join tbl_catalogos c on (e.id = c.tbl_empresa_id)
group by e.id;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Estava a um bom tempo já tentando fazer. Estava usando uma query super complicada e a solução era bem simples. Utilizei  a do GROUP BY, funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado novamente!

Comment: Recomendo você tirar um tempinho depois pra estudar as estruturas mais comuns de `SQL`! Leia sobre [`join`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/), `distinct`, `group by`, `order by`...
Todo mundo acaba precisando fazer consultas mais complicadas e gasta mais tempo tentando resolver um problema específico do que o tempo necessário pra estudar o básico de `SQL` :)

Comment: Eu vou sim. Mas a minha maior dificuldade nesse momento foi uma questão de logica pois eu estava tentando puxar tudo somente com Join e ect. A query tinha ficado enorme e não fazia o que eu precisava. Acho que por uma questão de pratica mesmo. Vou estudar e praticar mais essas questões.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.id
FROM tbl_empresa AS e
INNER JOIN tbl_catalogo AS c
ON e.id = c.tbl_empresa_id
```